# How to send multiple images using socket programing in java and write on specific path on server side?

Tags: java, sockets, file-transfer

I want to send multiple images from client side to server side on different systems in wifi and in server side write this files on specific location.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In Client.java file

```
public class Client {

    public void send(String file_name){
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("IBM-PC", 3332);
            File file = new File(file_name);
            System.out.println(file_name);
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(
                    socket.getInputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                    socket.getOutputStream());
            oos.writeObject(file.getName());
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[Server.BUFFER_SIZE];
            Integer bytesRead = 0;
            while ((bytesRead = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                oos.writeObject(bytesRead);
                oos.writeObject(Arrays.copyOf(buffer, buffer.length));
            }
            ois = null;
            oos = null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Client c = new Client();
        c.send("D://1.jpg");         // first image path
        c.send("D://0.jpg");        //  second image path
    }   
}
```

In Server.Java File

```
public class Server extends Thread {
    public static final int PORT = 3332;
    public static final int BUFFER_SIZE = 500102;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            while (true) {
                Socket s = serverSocket.accept();
                saveFile(s);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void saveFile(Socket socket) throws Exception {
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(
                socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        // 1. Read file name.
        Object o = ois.readObject();
        if (o instanceof String) {
            fos = new FileOutputStream("D:\\temp\\"+o.toString());  // Edit it for specific path
            System.out.println("D:\\temp\\"+o.toString());
        } else {
            throwException("Something is wrong");
        }
        // 2. Read file to the end.
        Integer bytesRead = 0;
        do {
            o = ois.readObject();
            if (!(o instanceof Integer)) {
                throwException("Something is wrong");
            }
            bytesRead = (Integer) o;
            o = ois.readObject();
            if (!(o instanceof byte[])) {
                throwException("Something is wrong");
            }
            buffer = (byte[]) o;
            // 3. Write data to output file.
            fos.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
        } while (bytesRead == BUFFER_SIZE);
        System.out.println("File transfer success");
        fos.close();
        ois.close();
        oos.close();
    }
    public static void throwException(String message) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception(message);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Server().start();
    }
}
```

> First run server.java file and then run client.java file

I hope it'll help you...

Comment: Terminating when `bytesRead != BUFFER_SIZE` is not correct. Short reads can occur at any time, not just at end of file. The sender should send a zero length,for an empty array, to  signal end of the current file. This code also writes more data than necessary. The byte array written should be bounded by `bytesRead`, not by `buffer.length`: and, having fixed that, you don't need to explicitly write `bytesRead` at all.